# Can't insert full strings in CSV file with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying a bit of everything now. Been a full 24 hour day on trying to understand why CSV doesn't save my file with plain words (no commas between letters). I still don't get it clearly. I tried with delimiters to no avail.

From the following code, I think that my loop iterates single letters only instead of words. But I don't know where my mistake is. Part of the code is here:

```
engine = input("Enter engine: ")
while STATUS != "q":
    keyword = input("Enter keyword(s): ")
    with open('list.csv', "a") as csvWriter, open('read.csv') as csvfile:
        if keyword != "q":
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvWriter, fieldnames=keyword, extrasaction='ignore')
            readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            writer.writeheader()
            for word in readCSV:
                writer.writerow(search_keyword(engine_name=engine, query_string=word))
        else:
            STATUS = "q"
            sys.exit(0)
```

Thanks for giving any clue. Much appreciated as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field names are a single string, so there's only one column in the CSV

If you're entering multiple keywords, you'll need to split it up, for example

```
fieldnames=keyword.split()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel silly after wasting so much time after this.

Comment: One quick question, if user input is a multiple-word keyword like a sentence, is there a way to not have the words of this sentence separated in one line e.g. with commas or other but just by keeping the spaces like in any sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but the split function defaults to all whitespacing

Comment: For example, my csv file contains: 'dogs, cats, cows, I like sheep, my name is John Doe'. Are the two previously-mentioned sentences going to be comma-separated as there are also spaces inside these sentences? I would like to keep the sentences as in this example, keeping the commas between these five entries.

Comment: Are those the "keywords"? Then you'd use `split(',')`, I guess

Comment: Yes, they are user input. Thanks, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure what your `search_keyword` function returns, but if the number of entries in its dictionary matches the number of keywords, then you'll have individual csv columns... In general, though, you should avoid putting commas within columns of a CSV

Comment: That's it. You're a king even when you're not sure.:) Good instinct. Thanks very much again.

Comment: split(',') did the job.